# Regex phone and email extraction output error - python

Tags: python, regex, copy, paste, pyperclip

The following program is used to extract phone number and email from the clipboard. The problem is whenever I copy something and run this code it gives the output as shown below:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
import pyperclip,re
phnRegex=re.compile(r'''(\+\d\d)?       #country code
                        (-|\s|\.)?      #seperator
                            (\d{10})    #numbers
                        ''',re.VERBOSE)

emailRegex=re.compile(r'''[a-zA-Z0-9._+%-]+           #username
                            @
                            [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+              #domain
                            (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})           #dot-something
                            ''',re.VERBOSE)
text=str(pyperclip.paste())
matches=[]
for groups in phnRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum='-'.join(groups[1],groups[3])
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])

if len(matches) > 0:
        pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
        print('Copied to clipboard:')
        print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No phone numbers or email addresses found.')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Sample Text that is copied is:

> General Queries:  flyingreturnsbase.ai@iclployalty.com 
> Missing Miles /
>   Retro Credit on AI:   airindiaretros.ai@iclployalty.com
>  Missing Miles /
>   Retro credit on Star Partners: starallianceretros.ai@iclployalty.com
>   Silver Edge Members:  silveredge.ai@iclployalty.com
>  Golden Edge
>   Members:  goldenedge.ai@iclployalty.com
>  The Maharajah Club
>   Members:  maharajahclub.ai@iclployalty.com

Comment: Could you please edit the post to include sample text that gets copied to clipboard?

Comment: @Matt.G Here it is....actually I used some random data. But here is a sample of email addresses only. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

change the capturing group in emailRegex to `(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})           #dot-something`

also, modify the for loops in the code to

```
for groups in phnRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0] + '-' + groups[2])
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/ThoseGleefulVirtualmachines)